# How to parse xml with varying number of children with rvest

Tags: r, xml, rvest

how do i parse this xml to get something like the desired result?  every configuration i've tried has grouped all five `a href=` links together in a single vector, but i need to distinguish the two results by `<div class="entry-content">`.  thanks!

```
# xml snippet from
# http://www.electionstudies.org/studypages/download/datacenter_all_NoData.html
my_xml <- 
    '<li class="clearfix">
    <article class="entry-item">
    <div class="entry-content">
    <h4 class="entry-title"><img src="../../images/icons/timeseries.png"><a href="../anes_timeseries_cdf/anes_timeseries_cdf.htm">ANES Time Series Cumulative Data File</a> (1948-2012)</h4>
    <p class="indented_text">Data documentation: &nbsp; <a href="../anes_timeseries_cdf/anes_timeseries_cdf.htm"> Study Page</a> &nbsp; <img src="../../images/icons/circle.png" /> &nbsp; <a href="../anes_timeseries_cdf/anes_timeseries_cdf_errata.htm">Errata</a></p>
    </div><!--entry-content-->
    </article><!--entry-item-->
    </li>
    <li class="clearfix">
    <article class="entry-item">
    <div class="entry-content">
    <h4 class="entry-title"><img src="../../images/icons/pilot.png"><a href="../anes_pilot_2016/anes_pilot_2016.htm">ANES 2016 Pilot Study</a></h4>
    <p class="indented_text">Data documentation: &nbsp; <a href="../anes_pilot_2016/anes_pilot_2016.htm">Study Page</a></p>
    </div><!--entry-content-->
    </article><!--entry-item-->
    </li>'

# desired result
list( 
    c( "../anes_timeseries_cdf/anes_timeseries_cdf.htm" , "../anes_timeseries_cdf/anes_timeseries_cdf.htm" , "../anes_timeseries_cdf/anes_timeseries_cdf_errata.htm" ) ,
    c( "../anes_pilot_2016/anes_pilot_2016.htm" , "../anes_pilot_2016/anes_pilot_2016.htm" )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(rvest)
library(purrr)

pg <- read_html("http://www.electionstudies.org/studypages/download/datacenter_all_NoData.html")

html_nodes(pg, "article") %>% 
  map(~html_nodes(., "a") %>% 
        html_attr("href"))
```

You need to ignore the first list result. If you want a solution that ignores the result for you with CSS selectors or XPath let me know.

Comment: thanks for making this possible. `devtools::install_github("ajdamico/lodown");library(lodown);lodown("anes",output_dir="C:/My Directory/ANES",your_email="email@address.com")`

Comment: *That's* a super-handy pkg.